# Make the line graph update based on the country clicked on the plotly choropleth map

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-express

I created the following script to display a plotly dash choropleth map and a `plotly.express` line graph. This is the gist of this data visualization application; the line graph should update a new line chart based on the country clicked, using the `clickData` event on the choropleth map. The map is working perfectly, based on the two dropdowns and sliders under `dcc.Dropdown` and `dcc.Slider` respectively. However, I have issues with creating a responsive line chart to the `clickData` event in the map. The default `clickData` value is "Kenya", however, when I click on a different country say "Botswana" I receive the following error circled in red:

[image]

I ensured I understood all I could from a similar [interactive graphing](https://dash.plotly.com/interactive-graphing) dash plotly article. I  tried an overly-amateurish idea of converting the `clickData` value (in the variable `country_name`) to string but didn't work. [ChatGPT suggestions](https://chat.openai.com/share/751cac11-2876-4b11-835b-eb68bcff12f3) were not helpful either.

Here is the Github link to the [dataframes used](https://github.com/sammigachuhi/dash_plotly_projects/tree/main/archive).

Here is the code:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
from dash import Dash, dcc, Input, Output, html

df_drinking = pd.read_csv("archive/Basic and safely managed drinking water services.csv")
df_sanitation = pd.read_csv("archive/Basic and safely managed sanitation services.csv")
df_handwashing = pd.read_csv("archive/Handwashing with soap.csv")
df_open_defecation = pd.read_csv("archive/Open defecation.csv")

dataframe_dict = {"Titles": ["Drinking_water_dataframe", "Sanitation_services_dataframe", "Handwashing_dataframe", "Open_defecation"],
              "Dataframes": ['drinking', 'sanitation', 'handwashing', 'open_defecation'] }

dataframe_table = pd.DataFrame(dataframe_dict)

# Function to get minimum and maximum year value in each dataframe
for dataframe in dataframe_table["Dataframes"]:
    if dataframe == "drinking":
        min_year = df_drinking["Year"].min()
        max_year = df_drinking["Year"].max()
    elif dataframe == "sanitation":
        min_year = df_sanitation["Year"].min()
        max_year = df_sanitation["Year"].max()
    elif dataframe == "handwashing":
        min_year = df_handwashing["Year"].min()
        max_year = df_handwashing["Year"].max()
    else:
        min_year = df_open_defecation["Year"].min()
        max_year = df_open_defecation["Year"].max()

# CSS styling
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    # The interactive plotly map
    html.Div(className="row", children=[

        html.Div(className="six columns", children=[
        # The Dropdown to select the dataframes
            dcc.Dropdown(#options=['df_drinking', 'df_handwashing'],
                options=dataframe_table["Dataframes"].unique(),
                value='drinking',
                id="dataframe_dropdown",
                style={"width": "50%", "display": "inline-block"})
        ]),

        html.Div(className="six columns", children=[
        # The Dropdown to select a value from the Residence Type column
            dcc.Dropdown(
                options=["Total", "Urban", "Rural"],
                value="Total",
                id="residence_area_type",
                style={"width": "40%", "display": "inline-block"}
            )
        ])
    ]),

    html.Br(),

    html.Div(id="dataframe_dropdown_output"),

    html.Br(),

    # The interactive plotly map
    dcc.Graph(id="sanitation_map", clickData={"points": [{"customdata": "Kenya"}]}),

    # Add slider for year
    dcc.Slider(min=min_year, max=max_year, value=min_year, step=None, marks={str(year): str(year) for year in range(min_year, max_year + 1)},
               included=False, id="year_slider"),

    # The Line graph
    dcc.Graph(id="line_graph")

])

# Show the selected dataframe
@app.callback(
    Output("dataframe_dropdown_output", "children"),
    Input("dataframe_dropdown", "value"),
    Input("residence_area_type", "value")
)
def dropdown_output(value, residence_value):
    return f"You have chosen the {value} dataframe and the {residence_value} Residence Area Type option"

# Draw a plotly map based on the dropdown value chosen
@app.callback(
    Output("sanitation_map", "figure"),
    Input("dataframe_dropdown", "value"),
    Input("year_slider", "value"),
    Input("residence_area_type", "value")
)
def choropleth_map(dataframe_dropdown, year_slider, residence_area_type):
    if dataframe_dropdown == "drinking":
        df = df_drinking
    elif dataframe_dropdown == "sanitation":
        df = df_sanitation
    elif dataframe_dropdown == "handwashing":
        df = df_handwashing
    else:
        df = df_open_defecation

    dff = df[df["Year"] == year_slider]
    dff = dff[dff["Residence Area Type"] == residence_area_type]
    dff = dff.sort_values(by="Year")

    fig = px.choropleth(dff, locations="Country", locationmode="country names", color="Display Value", projection="mercator",
                        hover_name="Country", scope="world", width=1000)

    fig.update_layout(margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0})

    return fig

# Draw the drinking line graph
## First create the function that will automatically plot the map based on country name (from hover), the dataframe
## selected (from dropdown) and the residence type (from dropdown also)
def check_dropdown(dataframe_dropdown):
    if dataframe_dropdown == "drinking":
        df = df_drinking
    elif dataframe_dropdown == "sanitation":
        df = df_sanitation
    elif dataframe_dropdown == "handwashing":
        df = df_handwashing
    else:
        df = df_open_defecation

    return df


# Now create the graph that updates the country name based on hover and showing Years on x-axis and Display value
# of chosen dataframe on y-axis
@app.callback(
    Output("line_graph", "figure"),
    Input("sanitation_map", "clickData"),
    Input("dataframe_dropdown", "value"),
    Input("residence_area_type", "value"),
)
def create_graph(clickData, dataframe_dropdown, residence_area_type):
    if clickData is None:
        country_name = "Kenya"
    else:
        country_name = clickData["points"][0]["customdata"]


    # country_name = clickData["points"][0]["customdata"]
    df = check_dropdown(dataframe_dropdown)

    dff = df[df["Country"] == country_name]
    dff = dff[dff["Residence Area Type"] == residence_area_type]

    dff.sort_values(by="Year")
    #
    fig = px.line(dff, x="Year", y="Display Value", markers=True)

    return fig

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

How do I make the line chart display the data for the country clicked, as referenced by `clickData` event in the `def create_graph` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a `"customdata"` key in `clickData["points"]` but only if you added some via `custom_data` when calling [`px.choropleth()`](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.express.choropleth.html) :

> `custom_data` (str, or list of str or int, or Series or array-like) –
> Either name or list of names of columns in data_frame, or pandas
> Series, or array_like objects Values from these columns are extra
> data, to be used in widgets or Dash callbacks for example.

The thing is that you actually don't need custom data (in this callback at least) : because you have set `hover_name="Country"` when building the figure, you can grab the country value on hover but also on click via `hovertext` :

```py
@app.callback(
    Output("line_graph", "figure"),
    Input("sanitation_map", "clickData"),
    Input("dataframe_dropdown", "value"),
    Input("residence_area_type", "value"),
)
def create_graph(clickData, dataframe_dropdown, residence_area_type):
    if clickData is None:
        country_name = "Kenya"
    else:
        country_name = clickData["points"][0]['hovertext']

    # ...
```

Comment: Setting the `country_name` variable to "hover_text" leads to another key error of 'hovertext'. So I reverted back to 'customdata'. Now I receive an error of `ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (13762,), (1,))` when clicking a country on the map.

Comment: I did not mention "hover_text" : `country_name = clickData["points"][0]['hovertext']`. It works on my side from the code you've provided. If you have an error, then edit your question to reflect the changes you have made and add the error message.

Comment: Apologies. That was a typo on my message. I actually inserted `hovertext` rather than `hover_text` as indicated.  The issue bringing up the `ValueError` in my response is that you meant that I *may* need the `customdata` in the `dcc.Graph(id="sanitation_map")`. Actually removing that `customdata`  from `dcc.Graph`  sorted out the error.  It should not be there at all if `hover_name` is already set to a variable in my `px.choropleth`. However, setting `custom_data` in `px.choropleth` and `country_name = clickData["points"][0]["hovertext"]` **when creating** the line chart works alright.

Comment: I didn't meant you may need customdata in dcc.Graph(), but in px.choropleth(). The point is you don't need custom data if you already have such data available as hovertext.

Comment: Hello, finally, while testing the code to destruction, to at least learn its intricacies, I realised one won't even need the `custom_data` parameter of `px.choropleth` so long as the `clickData` argument is in the `app.callback` callback function, and `hovertext` is parsed to it like so: `country_name = clickData["points"][0]["hovertext"]` as you had correctly said. I have posted the full working code as an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the [dash plotly tutorial example](https://dash.plotly.com/interactive-graphing) of updating graph on hover, in this case you should not insert `clickData={"points": [{"customdata": "Kenya"}]}` to the `dcc.Graph`. Instead, in the `app.callback` callback function, ensure you parse the argument `clickData` after the argument id of your `dcc.Graph`, in this case `sanitation_map`. Thereafter, parse `[hovertext]` to clickData to grab the country name like so: `country_name = clickData["points"][0]["hovertext"]`. You won't even need the `custom_data` parameter of `px.choropleth`.

The working code is shown below:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
from dash import Dash, dcc, Input, Output, html

df_drinking = pd.read_csv("archive/Basic and safely managed drinking water services.csv")
df_sanitation = pd.read_csv("archive/Basic and safely managed sanitation services.csv")
df_handwashing = pd.read_csv("archive/Handwashing with soap.csv")
df_open_defecation = pd.read_csv("archive/Open defecation.csv")

dataframe_dict = {"Titles": ["Drinking_water_dataframe", "Sanitation_services_dataframe", "Handwashing_dataframe", "Open_defecation"],
              "Dataframes": ['drinking', 'sanitation', 'handwashing', 'open_defecation'] }

dataframe_table = pd.DataFrame(dataframe_dict)

# Function to get minimum and maximum year value in each dataframe
for dataframe in dataframe_table["Dataframes"]:
    if dataframe == "drinking":
        min_year = df_drinking["Year"].min()
        max_year = df_drinking["Year"].max()
    elif dataframe == "sanitation":
        min_year = df_sanitation["Year"].min()
        max_year = df_sanitation["Year"].max()
    elif dataframe == "handwashing":
        min_year = df_handwashing["Year"].min()
        max_year = df_handwashing["Year"].max()
    else:
        min_year = df_open_defecation["Year"].min()
        max_year = df_open_defecation["Year"].max()

# CSS styling
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    # The interactive plotly map
    html.Div(className="row", children=[

        html.Div(className="six columns", children=[
        # The Dropdown to select the dataframes
            dcc.Dropdown(#options=['df_drinking', 'df_handwashing'],
                options=dataframe_table["Dataframes"].unique(),
                value='drinking',
                id="dataframe_dropdown",
                style={"width": "50%", "display": "inline-block"})
        ]),

        html.Div(className="six columns", children=[
        # The Dropdown to select a value from the Residence Type column
            dcc.Dropdown(
                options=["Total", "Urban", "Rural"],
                value="Total",
                id="residence_area_type",
                style={"width": "40%", "display": "inline-block"}
            )
        ])
    ]),

    html.Br(),

    html.Div(id="dataframe_dropdown_output"),

    html.Br(),

    # The interactive plotly map
    dcc.Graph(id="sanitation_map"),

    # Add slider for year
    dcc.Slider(min=min_year, max=max_year, value=min_year, step=None, marks={str(year): str(year) for year in range(min_year, max_year + 1)},
               included=False, id="year_slider"),

    # The Line graph
    dcc.Graph(id="line_graph")

])

# Show the selected dataframe
@app.callback(
    Output("dataframe_dropdown_output", "children"),
    Input("dataframe_dropdown", "value"),
    Input("residence_area_type", "value")
)
def dropdown_output(value, residence_value):
    return f"You have chosen the {value} dataframe and the {residence_value} Residence Area Type option"

# Draw a plotly map based on the dropdown value chosen
@app.callback(
    Output("sanitation_map", "figure"),
    Input("dataframe_dropdown", "value"),
    Input("year_slider", "value"),
    Input("residence_area_type", "value")
)
def choropleth_map(dataframe_dropdown, year_slider, residence_area_type):
    if dataframe_dropdown == "drinking":
        df = df_drinking
    elif dataframe_dropdown == "sanitation":
        df = df_sanitation
    elif dataframe_dropdown == "handwashing":
        df = df_handwashing
    else:
        df = df_open_defecation

    dff = df[df["Year"] == year_slider]
    dff = dff[dff["Residence Area Type"] == residence_area_type]
    dff = dff.sort_values(by="Year")

    fig = px.choropleth(dff, locations="Country", locationmode="country names", color="Display Value", projection="mercator",
                        hover_name="Country", scope="world", width=1000)

    fig.update_layout(margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0})

    return fig

# Draw the drinking line graph
## First create the function that will automatically plot the map based on country name (from hover), the dataframe
## selected (from dropdown) and the residence type (from dropdown also)
def check_dropdown(dataframe_dropdown):
    if dataframe_dropdown == "drinking":
        df = df_drinking
    elif dataframe_dropdown == "sanitation":
        df = df_sanitation
    elif dataframe_dropdown == "handwashing":
        df = df_handwashing
    else:
        df = df_open_defecation

    return df


# Now create the graph that updates the country name based on hover and showing Years on x-axis and Display value
# of chosen dataframe on y-axis
@app.callback(
    Output("line_graph", "figure"),
    Input("sanitation_map", "clickData"),
    Input("dataframe_dropdown", "value"),
    Input("residence_area_type", "value"),
)
def create_graph(clickData, dataframe_dropdown, residence_area_type):
    if clickData is None:
        country_name = "Kenya"
    else:
        country_name = clickData["points"][0]["hovertext"]


    # country_name = clickData["points"][0]["customdata"]
    df = check_dropdown(dataframe_dropdown)

    dff = df[df["Country"] == country_name]
    dff = dff[dff["Residence Area Type"] == residence_area_type]

    dff.sort_values(by="Year")
    #
    fig = px.line(dff, x="Year", y="Display Value", markers=True)

    return fig

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Now the line graph updates showing the statistics of each country clicked on the map.